# Georeferencer QGIS Import jp2 - Export jp2? - Is that possible?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, jpeg-2000

I would like to do a georeferencing via QGIS 3.22.5.
I'm using the standard implementation at the menu point "Raster" -> "Georeferencing". My import file is a jp2-format and then I'm going to find matching points out the scanned image with the real coordinates in QGIS. That's working very smoothly and without any problem.

Now dealing with my problem. When I'm starting the georeferencing I can only select "tif" as an output file. I'm afraid that these results are more than 370MB large in opposite to the import file by just 5MB.

Is there a solution or opportunity to import a jp2-file and get an jp2-format as output for importing in QGIS 3.22.5 or 3.10.5?

Comment: Output a geotiff (compressed if you prefer), translate to JP2, delete geotiff.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "Generate GDAL script" option of the georeferencer. It will generate two GDAL commands which look about this:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 494827 -7.0126e+06 3 6 -gcp 498813 -7.01243e+06 8 7 -gcp 498325 -7.00852e+06 5 4 "C:/data/georef.tif" "C:/Temp/georef.tif"
gdalwarp -r near -order 1 -co COMPRESS=None  -t_srs EPSG:4326 "C:/Temp/georef.tif" "C:/data/georef_modified.tif"
```

Edit the first command so that it writes out a VRT virtual raster instead of GeoTIFF. That is not necessary but writing out a temporary non-compressed tiff is just wasting of disk space. The file will be deleted anyway and VRT raster does all that is needed with a few lines of XML.

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -gcp 494827 -7.0126e+06 3 6 -gcp 498813 -7.01243e+06 8 7 -gcp 498325 -7.00852e+06 5 4 "C:/data/georef.tif" "C:/Temp/georef.vrt"
```

Edit the next command to use the VRT file as input and JP2 file as output.

```
gdalwarp -of JP2OpenJPEG -r near -order 1 -t_srs EPSG:4326 "C:/Temp/georef.vrt" "C:/data/georef_modified.jp2"
```

Check the driver documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/jp2openjpeg.html and also the gdalwarp documentation https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html for selecting reasonable options.

If your main concern is the file size of GeoTIFF, check the documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html. As you can see above, QGIS creates a command that will write an uncompressed GeoTIFF. By using JPEG compression `-co COMPRESS=JPEG` the file size is much smaller and if the image type allows, `-co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR` may save some 10-20% more.